# Сервер на node.js перестал отвечать после добавления headers

Tags: node.js

Создавал API сервер и всё перестало работать после добавления этого фрагмента:

```
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE , GET')
        return res.status(200).json({})
    }
})
```

Вот полный код:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const morgan = require('morgan')

const app = express()
const productRoutes = require('./routes/products')
const ordersRoutes = require('./routes/orders')

app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
//headers
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE , GET')
        return res.status(200).json({})
    }
})
//--headers
app.use('/products',productRoutes)
app.use('/orders',ordersRoutes)
//Обработочка ошибочек
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    const error = new Error('Not found')
    error.status = 404
    next(error)
})
app.use((error,req,res,next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500)
    res.json({
        error:{
            message:error.message
        }
    })
})
//Обработочка ошибочек--
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081 )
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся.

Так исправил чтобы работало:

```
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE , GET')
        return res.status(200).json({})
    }
    next()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень важно передать обработку запроса дальше. Вы забыли вызвать **next()**.

```
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо!Заработало)То как изменил код вставил в ответ.